# Where is pcd_viewer in ROS Hydro?

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It used to be [a part of perception_pcl](http://answers.ros.org/question/29982/how-do-i-install-pcd_viewer/), in ROS fuerte it [moved to the bin folder](http://answers.ros.org/question/41456/where-is-pcd_viewer-on-ros-fuerte/) but now I can't find it anywhere. Where is pcd_viewer in ROS Hydro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80836/where-is-pcd_viewer-in-ros-hydro?/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After prodding a while more, I found out pcd_viewer changed its name to pcl_viewer in PCL 1.7 and can be found in /usr/bin/pcl_viewer.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1